# Scipy maximum_filter is crazy

Tags: python, filter, scipy, max

I have a little problem with the maximum_filter function from scipy and don't get the solution.

I have three different numpy arrays.

```
a =  np.array([[-152, nan, -30, nan],
               [ nan, nan, nan, nan],
               [ nan, nan, nan, nan],
               [ nan, nan, nan, nan]])


b =  np.array([[ nan, nan, -30, nan],
               [ nan, nan, nan, nan],
               [ nan, nan, nan, nan],
               [ nan, nan, nan, nan]])


c =  np.array([[-152, nan, nan, nan],
               [ nan, nan, nan, nan],
               [ nan, nan, nan, nan],
               [ nan, nan, nan, nan]])
```

If I now want to calculate the maximum for a,b and c with

```
 maximum = (a == maximum_filter(a,3))
```

For a and c I get a maximum, but when I try it with b  I get no maximum.Why?

Is there a problem with the nans?

Comment: I suspect that the algorithm is doing a cumulative check on the max/min.  Since both `x > nan` and `x < nan` are false for numerical `x`, it fails to find the max when it is not at the upper left of the "window".  It just happens to work for your first two because you have a value in the upper left.  What are you doing that leaves you doing max filters on data with so many `nan`s?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.
That's above was a test to find the mistake.
I have Data with a lot backround noise from a sonar system. I have set a threshold to get rid of all the backround I don't want.

Comment: What values do you expect as output anyway? You say scipy is crazy, but so far, it's your data is crazy. Perhaps sanitize your data first (e.g., use masked arrays instead).

Comment: As Output I want to have the max values. I have an array with (223,701) shape. I want to find the maximum in an area of 3x3 and get them as output so I can work with them.

Comment: A workaround would be to change all NaNs to `-np.inf`: `b = np.where(np.isnan(b), -np.inf, b)`.

Comment: Ultimately I don't think something like a maximum is well-defined for datasets that include `nan`.