# NAN in scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter

Tags: python, filter, scipy, max

I don't quite understand the handling of NAN in the maximum_filter function. I expected either the NANs to be ignored or better if a nan appears anywhere in the kernel the result to be a NAN. Instead NANs seem to be treated differently depending on the place of appearance.

The problem seems to be a bit similar to [Scipy maximum_filter is crazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37270356/scipy-maximum-filter-is-crazy)

Here some example code, done with scipy version 0.19.1:

```
    import numpy as np
    import scipy.ndimage.filters

    a = np.array([[    0,     0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
                  [    0., np.nan,   1.,   2.,   3.,   2.],
                  [    0.,     0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
                  [    1.,     0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.]])

    b = np.array([[np.nan,     0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
                  [    0.,     0,   1.,   2.,   3.,   2.],
                  [    0.,     0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
                  [    1.,     0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.]])

    c = np.array([[np.nan,     0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
                  [    0., np.nan,   1.,   2.,   3.,   2.],
                  [    0.,     0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
                  [    1.,     0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.]])


    print(scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter(a, size=3))
    print(scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter(b, size=3))
    print(scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter(c, size=3))
```

Giving an output of

```
    [[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  4.]
     [ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  4.]
     [ 1.  1.  2.  3.  4.  4.]
     [ 1.  1.  2.  3.  4.  4.]]
    [[ nan  nan   2.   3.   4.   4.]
     [ nan  nan   2.   3.   4.   4.]
     [  1.   1.   2.   3.   4.   4.]
     [  1.   1.   2.   3.   4.   4.]]
    [[ nan  nan   2.   3.   4.   4.]
     [ nan  nan   2.   3.   4.   4.]
     [  1.   1.   2.   3.   4.   4.]
     [  1.   1.   2.   3.   4.   4.]]
```

In "a" NAN is ignored, in "b" it seems that every comparison with NAN results in NAN and "c" gives exactly the same result as "b".

Questions:
1. Is this a bug or can the behavior be somehow justified?
2. How can I get the "b" result for NANs not in the upper left corner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Try to avoid `nan`s with functions that don't explicitly state they have special `nan` handling. It's not-a-number, so don't use it where a number is expected!

SciPys `maximum_filter` is one of them.

I thought about going into the SciPy internals but since these are implementation details and might change without notice or deprecation it's probably not worth it. Also it will be really convoluted since it depends on the order of the comparisons and the comparison itself and also how the function does the `maximum_filter` (I suspect they use a heap-based running maximum filter).

However you can of course get the desired results. If you want `NaN`s to be ignored you can replace them (for `maximum_filter`) with `-np.inf` and if you want them to be to be "propagated" then you could use for example a generic filter:

```
def maximum_filter_ignore_nan(array, *args, **kwargs):
    nans = np.isnan(array)
    replaced = np.where(nans, -np.inf, array)
    return scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter(replaced, *args, **kwargs)


def maximum_filter_propagate_nan(array, *args, **kwargs):
    def inner(array):
        if np.isnan(array).any():
            return np.nan
        return array.max()
    return scipy.ndimage.generic_filter(arr, inner, size=3)

print(maximum_filter_ignore_nan(a, size=3))
print(maximum_filter_ignore_nan(b, size=3))
print(maximum_filter_ignore_nan(c, size=3))

print(maximum_filter_propagate_nan(a, size=3))
print(maximum_filter_propagate_nan(b, size=3))
print(maximum_filter_propagate_nan(c, size=3))
```

Comment: Do I understand it right, that it boils down to: "Do never use nans!", since the implementation even in python is poor? Does the same hold true for +/-inf? It's not a number either. The answer doesn't solve my problem, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @B.Biehler No, you can use `nan`s, for example NumPy has a whole lot of `np.nan*` functions, e.g. [`nanmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmax.html#numpy.nanmax). Also +/- inf is a number! It's just NaNs that behave (sometimes) weird. The problem is the fact that nan isn't equal to anything (not even itself) and that any comparison with nan should return false. That breaks a whole lot of assumptions that are valid for all other numbers (even inf).

Comment: @B.Biehler I updated the answer with some alternatives that you could use to archieve the expected result.